# "Generic" power bricks for external disks?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply

I’ve found some old external USB drives and drive enclosures. Some of them, I found the power bricks and cords for, others I haven’t, and a few have cords damaged sufficiently that they are unsafe to use. For the ones where the brick is missing or the cord damaged, can I purchase an "off-the-shelf" brick-and-cord system and use it successfully, provided that the brick’s output (both voltage and amperage) is equal to or higher than that required by the drive/drive enclosure, and that I have a compatible plug?

Comment: Provided the brick supplies the same voltage it should be fine.  The brick can support higher amperage, but if a device attempts to draw more amperage then the brick can support, that can be a safety issue.  You typically just want to use a power brick that can supply exactly the same power as the OEM brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, ***yes***, it would be okay to purchase a generic power supply for your device; there isn't a specific requirement that the device must have its original power brick/supply

When looking for a replacement power supply, the voltage provided by the supply must be approximately the voltage required by the device, although there is a tolerance, so usually it's no problem to e.g. supply a 5V device with 5.5V.

With regards to amperage/current, however, the device will only take what it needs.

Comment: So if I need to deal with devices that need 5V and devices that need 12V, I need two separate bricks? A single 12V brick risks damage to the 5V device?

Comment: Yes, that's correct; **voltage is pushed**, **amperage is pulled**. If you plug a supply rated 12V into a device that accepts 5V, it will damage it.